# Добавление объектов в массив

Tags: массивы, objective-c

Начал изучать objective c. Придумал такую задачу:

- Создать простое окно "регистрации" пользователей(логин, пароль, дата рождения, пол, о себе). Есть класс forObject, в котором описываются все объекты интерфейса(текстовые поля, кнопки) и метод обработки нажатия кнопки "Register". Так же есть класс userData, содержит поля для хранения введенной инфы о пользователе. Хочу по нажатию кнопки register создавать объект класса userData и передавать конструктору данные, введенные пользователем. Затем этот объект добавить в массив.

[image: http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/01/b1b2fe7f9b23f421b9b36c26e01cc08d.png]

---

У меня сразу возникло несколько трудностей:

1. Как создать конструктор, который будет принимать значения из переменных, в которых хранятся данные, введенные юзером в диальговом окне?
2. Как создать объект класса userData в классе forObject.

Буду очень благодарен тому, кто поможет. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Во-первый переименуйте классы в соответствии с рекомендациями, имя класса должно всегда начинаться с Заглавных букв. Вы можете сделать это безболезненно, перейдя в заголовочный файл класса, выделить его название forObject, нажать правую кнопку и выбрать Refactor->Rename

описываем класс UserData

```
@interface UserData: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *login;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger gender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *bDate;

@end
```

**Конструктор**

```
 + (instancetype)userDataWith:(NSString *)login password:(NSString *)password // и так далее все необходимые вам значения для конструирования объекта
```

далее имплементация

```
 + (instancetype)userDataWith:(NSString *)login password:(NSString *)password {
     UserData *userData = [[self alloc] init];
     userData.login = login;
     userData.password = password;
     /* ... */
     return userData;
}
```

**Для хранения значений переменных вам нужно создать необходимые**

`@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *loginString;` и так далее

далее создаем необходимые IBAction или просто добавляем таргеты для UI элементов

```
 - (IBAction)loginFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
     self.loginString = textField.text;
}
```

**Как создать объект UserDara в классе ForObject**

в ForObject.m делаем:

```
#import "UserData.h"

@interface ForObject ()
@property (nonatomic, string) NSArray *registeredUsers;
@end

@implementation ForObject

/* ... */

 - (NSArray *)registeredUsers { // здесь мы инициализируем пустой массив при первом обращении в registeredUsers через self.registeredUsers
    if (!_registeredUsers) {
         _registeredUsers = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _registeredUsers;
}

- (IBAction)registedPressed:(id)sender { // добавляем обработчик нажатия кнопки Register
    UserData *userData = [UserData userDataWithLogin:self.loginString ...]; // создаем новый объект UserData
    self.registeredUsers = [self.registeredUsers arrayByAddingObject:userData]; // добавляем его в массив
}

/* ... */
@end
```

еще хочу посоветовать не заморачиваться с конструктором, так как он тут принимает множество параметров, лучше всего сделать так

в интерфейс класса ForObject добавляем текущего регистрируемого пользователя

```
@property (nonatomic, string) UserData *registeringUserData;
```

создаем Lazy Load геттер для этой проперти

```
- (UserData *)registeringUserData {
    if (!_registeringUserData) {
         _registeringUserData = [UserData new];
    }
    _registeringUserData;
}
```

далее привязываем обработчики событий редактирования UI элементов в них работаем напрямую в объектом UserData, например:

```
 - (IBAction)passwordFiledDidChange:(UITextField *)sender {
    self.registeringUserData.password = sender.text;
}
```

далее меняем обработчик нажатия regirsted:

```
- (IBAction)registedPressed:(id)sender { // добавляем обработчик нажатия кнопки Register
        self.registeredUsers = [self.registeredUsers arrayByAddingObject:self.registeringUserData]; // добавляем его в массив
        self.registeringUserData = nil; // не забываем прибраться чтобы при новом обращении создался новый UserData
    }
```

Comment: Больше спасибо за ответ. В общем все проясняется. Только хотел спросить почему переменные pass, login... описанные в интерфейсе класса UserData не видимы в конструкторе. т.е стока userData.login = login;
подчеркивается. И выпадающее меню(с подсказками, после точки) не содержит вообще этих переменных?

Comment: единственное, я так понимаю, что вы пишете под OS X, тогда у вас будет не UITextField, а OS X аналог, в остальном все также

Comment: проапдейтил свой ответ посмотрите описание класса UserData